# Firebase SPM brings lots of Warning under iOS15

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swift-package-manager, ios15

Using XCode13.1, iOS15.1, Swift5.5.1 :

The Swift Package Manager is great and it improved again under iOS15.

However, my observation is that even big companies do not fully embrace its usage.

One painful experience at the moment is: Google Firebase integration with SPM.

It is mostly their sub-dependencies that cause lots of Warning messages inside Xcode.

Google Firebase 8.9.1 integration with Swift Package Manager uses the following two sub-dependencies :

- abseil 0.20200225.3
- BoringSSL-GRPC 0.7.1
- others...

In the Project Navigator of Xcode you can immediately see the Warning-Signs.

[image]

When compiling my project there are 37 Warnings due to the two above sub-dependencies of Firebase. The compiler prints the following warnings:

[image]

What is there to do ?

When is Google updating their Firebase dependencies appropriate for iOS15 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xcode, do `File -> Packages -> Update to latest Package Versions` to get the fixes in abseil 0.202200225.4, BoringSSL-GRPC 0.7.2, etc.

Comment: super, fantastic - I did not know this Xcode-feature yet.